# Order list in Certain Order in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list made ​​up from the following class:

```
public class Category
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string slug { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public int parent { get; set; }
            public int post_count { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the list.

```
List<Category> cats = new List<Category>();
```

I wish I could sort it according to the id (int), but in a certain order i have:

3, 17, 13, 176, 4, 177, 179, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 139

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] orderData = new[] {3, 17, 13, 176, 4, 177, 179, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 139};
List<Category> orderedCategories = cats.OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(orderData, item.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: I select this answer for simplicity, but they are all equally valid. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm assuming that what you mean is that you'd like to sort in the order

```
3, 17, 13, 176, 4, 177, 179, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 139
```

... rather than in strict numeric order.

Can you add a SortOrder field to the class?

If you can't, you might be able to emulate one.  Create a class that has two properties, ID and SortOrder:

```
public class CategorySortOrder
{
    int CategoryId { get;set;}
    int SortOrder { get;set;}
}
```

Create an array of those, in the right order:

```
var catSortOrder = new[] {
   new CategorySortOrder() { CategoryId = 3, SortOrder = 1 },
   new CategorySortOrder() { CategoryId = 17, SortOrder = 2 }
   // etc.
   }
```

Then execute some LINQ:

```
var catList = from cat in cats 
              join so in catSortOrder on cat.id = so.CategoryId
              select new {
                cat = cat,
                sort_order = so.SortOrder
              };
var finalist = catList
                  .OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder)
                  .Select(item => item.cat)
                  .ToList();
```

If all you mean is that you want the IDs to be in numeric order, you can sort them with LINQ, like this:

```
var catList = cats.OrderBy(cat => cat.id).ToList();
```

Comment: This is wrong! OrderBy Doesn't sort in place, it returns an Orderd Enumerable.

Comment: That's true, but I didn't intend to imply it did.  I have added the target variable to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

- Implementing your own comparer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx ) and then calling the method Sort() on the collection;
- Using LINQ on a certain attribute, since you mention ID:

  ```
  var sortedCats=cats.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `Comparer`:

```
public class CategoryComparer : IComparer<Category>
{
    List<int> orderNums =
        new List<int> { 3, 17, 13, 176, 4, 177, 179, 178, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 139 };

    public int Compare(Category x, Category y)
    {
        var index1 = orderNums.IndexOf(x.id);
        var index2 = orderNums.IndexOf(y.id);

        if (index1 == index2)
            return 0;

        return index1 > index2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Then `Sort` the list using the new `Comparer`:

```
cats.Sort(new CategoryComparer());
```

Or use LINQ to leave the original list untouched:

```
var sortedCats = cats.OrderBy(x => x, new CategoryComparer());
```